# Android Espresso onData with doesNotExist

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to verify that a `ListView` does not contain a particular item.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Contact.class)), is(withContactItemName(is("TestName")))))
      .check(doesNotExist());
```

When the name exists, I correctly get an error because of `check(doesNotExist())`.  When the name does not exist, I get the following error, because `allOf(...)` doesn't match anything:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: 
(is an instance of layer.sdk.contacts.Contact and is with contact item name:
is "TestName")
```

How can I get functionality like `onData(...).check(doesNotExist())`?

**EDIT:**

I have a terrible hack to get the functionality I'd like by using try/catch and inspecting the event's getCause().  I would love to replace this with a good technique.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Espresso samples you must not use `onData(...)` to check if view doesn't exists in adapter. Check this out - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes?hl=en#asserting-data-item-not-in-adapter). Read "Asserting that a data item is not in an adapter" part. You have to use a matcher together with `onView()` that finds the AdapterView.

Based on Espresso samples from link above:

1. matcher:

   ```
    private static Matcher<View> withAdaptedData(final Matcher<Object> dataMatcher) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with class name: ");
                dataMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                if (!(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
                    return false;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Adapter adapter = ((AdapterView) view).getAdapter();
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (dataMatcher.matches(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
   ```
2. then `onView(...)`, where `R.id.list` is the id of your adapter ListView:

   ```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testDataItemNotInAdapter(){
        onView(withId(R.id.list))
            .check(matches(not(withAdaptedData(is(withContactItemName("TestName"))))));
    }
   ```

And one more suggestion - to avoid writing `is(withContactItemName(is("TestName"))` add below code to your matcher:

```
    public static Matcher<Object> withContactItemName(String itemText) {
        checkArgument( itemText != null );
        return withContactItemName(equalTo(itemText));
    }
```

then you'll have more readable and clear code `is(withContactItemName("TestName")`