# Select dialog option in Espresso with ArrayAdapter and Material v7 Support library

Tags: android, testing, android-dialog, android-espresso

I have a dialog with a list with elements where each one is supplied with an ArrayAdapter:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ArrayList<String> names = getArguments().getStringArrayList(INTENT_OPTIONS);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                if (mListener != null){
                    mListener.onSelectedElement(which);
                }
            }
        };

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.loginActivity_selectVACenter)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setAdapter(adapter, listener)
                .create();
    }
```

Before implementing the appcompat v7 library to incorporate material features, I selected each element in Espresso with the following sentence:

```
onView(withText("text of the entry"))
                    .perform(click());
```

But after adding this library, this sentence does not work anymore, Espresso cannot find the view and throws a NoMatchingViewException.

Is there any other way to access the dialog options?

Comment: Add please a screenshot of this dialog and of course a full log of `NoMatchingViewException`

Answer (score 1):

I've already found this topic which might be helpful: [Check if a dialog is displayed with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045509/check-if-a-dialog-is-displayed-with-espresso)

In one of possible answers there is a `getRootView()` matcher:

> To answer question 4, which the accepted answer does not, I modified
>   the following code, which I found here on Stack Overflow
>   ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28606603/2740621)) for testing
>   whether a Toast was displayed.
>
> ```
> @NonNull
> public static ViewInteraction getRootView(@NonNull Activity activity, @IdRes int id) {
>     return onView(withId(id)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(activity.getWindow().getDecorView()))));
> }
> ```
>
> The `id` passed in is the id of a `View` currently displayed in your
>   dialog. You could also write the method like so:
>
> ```
> @NonNull
> public static ViewInteraction getRootView(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull String text) {
>     return onView(withText(text)).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(activity.getWindow().getDecorView()))));
> }
> ```
>
> And now it's looking for a `View` containing a particular text string.
>
> Use it like so:
>
> ```
> getRootView(getActivity(), R.id.text_id).perform(click());
> ```

Try this at first. Also in the same topic you would find this method:

> onView(withText(R.string.my_title)).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

If it still doesn't work it would might to use `onData` matcher.

> Whenever you have a ListView, GridView, Spinner, and other Adapter
>   based views, you’ll have to use onData() in order to interact with an
>   item from that list. onData() is targeting directly the data provided
>   by your adapter. What does this mean, we will see in a moment.[[1]](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/an-introduction-to-espresso/)

You can read about it here:

[Get started with a simple test using onData](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/basics/#get-started-with-a-simple-test-using-ondata)

[[codepath] UI Testing with Espresso](https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Espresso)

[Android Espresso onData with doesNotExist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173253/android-espresso-ondata-with-doesnotexist)

Comment: Look for using  `scrollTo()` in Espresso like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410613/android-espresso-scrolling-to-a-non-list-view-item